# Simple macro doesn't seem to execute given forms

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm using this basic macro as a building block for other timing macros:

```
(defmacro time-pure
  "Evaluates expr and returns the time it took.
  Modified the native time macro to return the time taken."
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (current-nano-timestamp)
         ret# ~expr]
     (/ (double (- (current-nano-timestamp) start#)) 1000000.0)))
```

I've tested this, and used it in other macros, so I know it works fine.

My problem can be described by the following snippet:

```
(defmacro time-each [& exprs]
  `(mapv #(time-pure %) '~exprs))
```

I would expect this to give each expression to `time-each`, where it executes and times it; returning the result. When I test it however, it finishes instantly:

```
(time-each
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (Thread/sleep 1000))

[0.036571 0.0]
```

I'm confused by this since I know that `(time-pure (Thread/sleep 1000))` will take around a second to return, and all this macro does it delegate to `time-pure`.

What's causing this? I really have no idea how to properly debug a macro. I used `macro-expand-1` to inspect the generated code:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint
  (macroexpand-1
    '(time-each
      (Thread/sleep 500)
      (Thread/sleep 1000))))

(clojure.core/mapv
 (fn*
  [p1__1451__1452__auto__]
  (helpers.general-helpers/time-pure p1__1451__1452__auto__))
 '((Thread/sleep 500) (Thread/sleep 1000)))
```

But nothing really stands out to me.

What's going on here?

(Note, this is a dupe of a question I posted a few minutes ago. I realized the case I was showing was convoluted, so I made up a better example.)

Comment: Would you like me to dupe-link the other one to this one?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Well, I deleted it, so only very high level users will be able to see it. It's basically identical save for the code used. In retrospect, I probably should have just edited the original. I'm not sure why I made a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defmacro time-each [& exprs]
  `(list ~@(for [expr exprs]
             `(time-pure ~expr))))
```

You need to be careful not to evaluate an expression outside of a `time-pure` context, as is done in Arthur's answer, which evaluates each expression and then calls `time-pure` on the (very fast) operation of "looking at the result". Rather, wrap `time-pure` around each expression before evaluating it.

Comment: What is it about this that prevents the expressions from being evaluated before being given to `time-pure`? Sorry, I'm still trying to don't wrap my head around macros.

Comment: And I noticed on some of your macro answers, you use `for` over `map`. I'd there a particular reason for that, or is it just personal style?

Comment: Seems to be the cleanest and most straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm missing some context here. Where is "Arthur's answer"?

Comment: @pdoherty926, I believe Arthur's answer has been deleted for some reason.

Comment: @pdoherty926 His answer didn't work right, so I think he deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

I think what happens here is that your `mapv` executes after compile time, meaning at run time, this is why it cant just "paste" the code list as an sexp. I think a better approach would be to keep the `mapv` out of the syntax quoting:

```
(defmacro each-time-mine [& exprs]
  (mapv #(time-pure %) exprs))


(each-time-mine
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (Thread/sleep 1000))

[501.580465 1001.196752]
```

**Original**

Although `eval` is usually frowned upon, it seems to solve the problem in this situation:

```
(defmacro time-pure
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (current-nano-timestamp)
         ret# (eval ~expr)]
     (/ (double (- (current-nano-timestamp) start#)) 1000000.0)))

(defmacro time-each [& exprs]
  `(mapv #(time-pure %) '~exprs))

(time-each
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (Thread/sleep 1000))

[501.249249 1001.242522]
```

What happens is that `mapv` sees the sexps as lists, and at the moment `time-pure` wants to execute them, it simply assigns `ret#` the value of the list. So that list needs to be `eval`ed.

There might be better ways to achieve this though.

Comment: Why is `eval` required in this case though when `time-pure` works fine when used directly? I think I need to think about this again tomorrow morning. Macros are rotting my brain :/

Comment: with a -1, a polite comment explaining the reason goes a long way.

Comment: Idk why you're downvoted. Maybe the use of `eval` triggered someone? I'll upvote to offset though as I really want to understand what's going on here, and this is a different take.

Comment: Gotta love automatic reactions! In any case, if `eval` is ever the answer, it probably means something that should evaluate at compiled time has moved into run-time. Peace! :)

Comment: I have noticed that some troll frequently downvotes answers that are not considered to be "pure enough".  Even if they use nothing but basic functions!

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I think `eval` is probably a little overkill for this though.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I only used it before realizing simply moving the statement out of the quote would do.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm still trying to don't wrap my head around macros."

It takes a while. :) One thing that helped me was macro-expanding:

```
(macroexpand-1  '(time-each (+ 2 2 )(+ 3 3)))
```

That produces:

```
(clojure.core/mapv
    (fn* [p1__24013__24014__auto__] 
        (rieclj.core/time-pure p1__24013__24014__auto__))
    (quote ((+ 2 2) (+ 3 3))))
```

The alarming thing there is that time-pure is being passed a quoted list, so it is all just symbols at *run time*, not macroexpansion time.

Then another thing that helped me was that the beauty of Lispy macros is that they are  normal functions that just run at a different time (while the reader is processing the source). But because they are normal functions we can probe them with print statements just as we probe normal code.

I have modified time-pure to print out its macroexpansion-time argument expr and, in the generate code, to have it print out the evaluated input, which we now suspect is a list of symbols, or '(+ 2 2) in the first case.

```
(defmacro time-pure
  "Evaluates expr and returns the time it took.
   Modified the native time macro to return the time taken."
  [expr]
 (prn :time-pure-sees expr)
 `(let [start# (now)
        ret# ~expr]
    (prn :ret-is ret# (type (first  ret#)))
    (/ (double (- (now) start#)) 1000000.0)))
```

I print the type of the first of ret to drive home that + is a symbol, not a function. Evaluating:

```
(time-each (+ 2 2 )(+ 3 3))
```

yields:

```
:time-pure-sees p1__24013__24014__auto__
:ret-is (+ 2 2) clojure.lang.Symbol
:ret-is (+ 3 3) clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Seeing (+ 2 2) might make you think all is well, but the key is that the rightside is '(+ 2 2) so ret# gets bound to that symbolic expression instead of the intended computation.

Again, printing the type of the first hopefully makes clear that time-pure was working on a list of symbols at runtime.

Sorry if all that was confusing, but the moral is simple: use macroexpand-1 and embedded print statements when macros mess with your head. In time you will internalize the two different times, macroexpansion and run.